# How do i center this lightbox image gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

I want to know how to center this lightbox. Here is a link to the code - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_lightbox . I scaled the image down by changing the width of the column class from 25% to 15% and the lightbox floats to the left. I want it to be centered. Thanks

Comment: Try display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto

Comment: This works when i type it into the column class and get rid of the float tag but now all the images have a new row. How do i keep them in the same row?

Comment: Do <div class="col-md-3"></div> for each image

Comment: That requires bootstrap. Do you think you could add in the bootstrap code for me because it didn't work when i tried it.